# How many ways can 5 dice produce a total of 20?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> How many ways can $5$ dice produce a total of $20$?

I set up the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 20$. The total possible number of combinations is $\binom{19}4$. From there I subtracted the number of possibilities where $1$ of the variables is greater than $6$, which I got as $5\times\binom{13}4$. I also subtracted the possibilities where $2$ variables is greater than $6$, which I used $10 \times \binom74$. I got the $10$ from the number of ways I can choose $2$ of the variables to be greater than $6$ out of the $5$ total variables.

So I have $$\binom{19}4 -5\times\binom{13}4 -10\times\binom74$$

However, I get a negative answer, which can't be right. Can anyone point a flaw in my logic?

Comment: What is "oridyce"?

Comment: @Théophile Maybe Euridice. Ask Orpheus :)

Comment: Ahhh, meant to write produce :S

Comment: Please just edit the question.

Comment: Hint: Assuming each die shows a number from 1 to 6, each $x_i \ge 1$.  This means you need to modify your equation to read $x_1+\cdots+x_5=15$.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude any combination where one of the variables is greater than 5? And if you have already excluded every case where one variable is greater than 5, how can two variables be greater than 6?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. It should be greater than 6. I'm subtracting the possibilities where exactly 1 variable is more than 6, and where 2 variables are more than 6. Three variables can't be greater than 6, so no need to go farther than that.

Comment: The number of ways that $5$ dice can sum to $20$ is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5$, which is $651$.

Comment: @user154817, you are all right except it is alternating sums.  So, it is $C(19,4) - 5*C(13,4) + 10*C(7,4) = 651. The second term includes the third term and the third term is adding back.

Answer (score 6):

As in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/710464), we can approach this question using either generating functions or inclusion-exclusion. Instead of counting the number of ways for $5$ numbers from $1$ to $6$ to sum to $20$, we will count the number of ways for $5$ numbers from $0$ to $5$ to sum to $15$ (then add $1$ to each of the $5$ numbers).

---

**Generating Functions**

The generating function for the number of ways for $5$ integers from $0$ to $5$ to sum to a given number is
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5
&=\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^5\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}(-1)^kx^{6k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-5}{j}(-x)^j\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}(-1)^kx^{6k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+4}{j}x^j\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
We can get the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $(1)$ by choosing $6k+j=15$:
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}\sum_{k=0}^5(-1)^k\binom{5}{k}\binom{15-6k+4}{15-6k}
&=\binom{5}{0}\binom{19}{15}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{13}{9}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{3}\\
&=651\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Inclusion-Exclusion**

Without restriction on the size of the terms, using the standard $\mid$ and $\circ$ argument ($15$ $\circ$s and $4$ $\mid$s), there are $\binom{15+4}{4}$ ways to choose 5 non-negative integers that sum to $15$.
$$
\text{one sum for each arrangement}\\
2+4+6+1+2=\circ\,\circ\mid \circ\circ\circ\,\circ\mid \circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\,\circ\mid\circ\mid \circ\circ
$$
Now let's count how many ways there are to have terms greater than $5$. There are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to choose which $1$ term should be greater than $5$. To count the number of sums with $1$ term at least $6$, that would be $\binom{15-6+4}{4}$.
$$
\text{consider the red group atomic}\\
2+7+3+2+1=\circ\,\circ\mid\color{#C00000}{\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ}\circ\mid\circ\circ\circ\mid\circ\,\circ\mid\circ
$$
There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose which $2$ terms should be greater than $5$. To count the number of sums with $2$ terms at least $6$, that would be $\binom{15-12+4}{4}$.
$$
7+0+6+1+1=\color{#C00000}{\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ}\circ\mid\mid\color{#C00000}{\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\,\circ}\mid\circ\mid\circ
$$
There is no way for $3$ terms to be greater than $5$. Inclusion-Exclusion says there are
$$
\binom{19}{4}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{13}{4}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{4}=651
$$
ways for $5$ terms to sum to $15$ with each term at most $5$.

---

**Problem in the question**

With Inclusion-Exclusion, the terms in the sum are alternating. If the last $-$ sign is changed to a $+$, your answer would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum of the five dice is either $4, 5$, or $6$.  Reasoning:

If the maximum of all five is $6$, then the maximum of the remaining four is $4, 5$ or $6$, because $6+3+3+3+3 < 20.$  If the maximum of all five is $5$, then the maximum of the remaining four is $4$ or $5$, because $5+3+3+3+3 < 20.$  If the maximum of all five is $4$, then they're all $4$.  The maximum cannot be $3$ or less because $3+3+3+3+3 < 20.$

If the top two dice are $6,6$, the sum of the other three is $8$.  Five combinations with all three $\leq 6$: $$(6,1,1), (5,2,1), (4,3,1), (4,2,2), (3,3,2).$$

If the top two dice are $6,5$, the sum of the other three is $9$.  Five combinations with all three $\leq 5$: $$(5,3,1), (5,2,2), (4,4,1), (4,3,2), (3,3,3).$$

If the top two dice are $6,4$, the sum of the other three is $10$.  Two combinations with all three $\leq 4$: $$(4,4,2), (4,3,3).$$

If the top two dice are $5,5$, the sum of the other three is $10$.  Four combinations with all three $\leq 5$: $$(5,4,1), (5,3,2), (4,4,2), (4,3,3).$$

If the top two dice are $5,4$, the sum of the other three is $11$.  Just one combination with all three $\leq 4$:  $$(4,4,3).$$

Finally, there's $(4,4,4,4,4).$

So, there are $18$ combinations of $5$ dice that add up to $20$.

**Edit**:  If order matters, then you'll need to consider the distinct permutations of each combination above.  For each combination, there are $5!/n_i$ permutations, where

$$n_i =
  \begin{cases}
   2! = 2 & \text{if there is one pair}\\
   2!2! = 4       & \text{if there are two pair}\\
   3! = 6 & \text{if there are three of a kind}\\
   3!2! = 12 & \text{if it's a full house}\\
   5! = 120 & \text{if it's a yahtzee}\\
  \end{cases}
$$

It's straightforward to verify that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{18} \frac{5!}{n_i} = 651.$$

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the order of the dice doesn't matter?

Comment: Ahhhh ... NOW you tell me! :)  I edited my answer.

Comment: Given $i$, how does one compute $n_i$?

Comment: @robjohn I have $18$ combinations in the first part of my answer.  $i=1$ is the first one, $i=2$ is the second one, and so forth.  Computing $n_i$ is by inspection of the combination as to whether it has one pair, two pair, etc.  For the combination $(6,6,6,1,1)$ this is a full house, so $n_1 = 12,$ and the number of permutations of this particular combination is $120/12 = 10.$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{0 < a < 1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{6}\ldots%
\sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{6}\ds{\delta_{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i},\ 20}}}
=\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{6}\ldots\sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{6}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{21 - \sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{21}}
\pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{6}z^{n}}^{5}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{21}}\pars{z\,{z^{6} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{5}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
{\pars{1 - z^{6}}^{5} \over z^{16}\pars{1 - z}^{5}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-5 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
{\pars{1 - z^{6}}^{5} \over z^{16 - n}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 4 \choose 4}
\sum_{k = 0}^{5}{5 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\ \underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
{1 \over z^{16 - n - 6k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{\delta_{n\ +\ 6k,\, 15}}}
\\[3mm]&=\left.\sum_{k = 0}^{5}{\bracks{15 - 6k} + 4 \choose 4}{5 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\right\vert_{15\ -\ 6k\ \geq\ 0}
=\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\pars{-1}^{k}{19 - 6k \choose 4}{5 \choose k}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{6}\ldots%
> \sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{6}\ds{\delta_{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i},\ 20}}}
> ={19 \choose 4}{5 \choose 0}- {13 \choose 4}{5 \choose 1}
> +{7 \choose 4}{5 \choose 2}
> \\[3mm]&=3876\times 1 - 715\times 5 + 35\times 10
> =\color{#00f}{\Large 651}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If the dice are all white and tossed on a table, then order doesn't matter. By listing them, I find there are only 18 ways that five dice can add to 20:

```
    [1, 1, 6, 6, 6]
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 6]
    [1, 3, 4, 6, 6]
    [1, 3, 5, 5, 6]
    [1, 4, 4, 5, 6]
    [1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
    [2, 2, 4, 6, 6]
    [2, 2, 5, 5, 6]
    [2, 3, 3, 6, 6]
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    [2, 3, 5, 5, 5]
    [2, 4, 4, 4, 6]
    [2, 4, 4, 5, 5]
    [3, 3, 3, 5, 6]
    [3, 3, 4, 4, 6]
    [3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
    [3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

However, if the dice are lined up so that order is considered to be an important part of the question, then you can take the 18 items and expand from there just as I did in the following Python (programming language) script.  Note that, in Python, ans += x will simply cause x to be added to ans.

```
    from math import factorial as fac
    f = fac(5)                    # `fac` denotes `factorial`
    ans = 0                       # `ans` denotes `answer`
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 3))    # [1, 1, 6, 6, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2))            # [1, 2, 5, 6, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2))            # [1, 3, 4, 6, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2))            # [1, 3, 5, 5, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2))            # [1, 4, 4, 5, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 3))            # [1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 2))    # [2, 2, 4, 6, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 2))    # [2, 2, 5, 5, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 2))    # [2, 3, 3, 6, 6]
    ans += f                      # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 3))            # [2, 3, 5, 5, 5]
    ans += f/(fac( 3))            # [2, 4, 4, 4, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 2))    # [2, 4, 4, 5, 5]
    ans += f/(fac( 3))            # [3, 3, 3, 5, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 2))    # [3, 3, 4, 4, 6]
    ans += f/(fac( 2)*fac( 2))    # [3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
    ans += f/(fac( 3))            # [3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
    ans += f/(fac( 5))            # [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
    print ans
```

The answer printed out is 651.  My approach is similar to John's above.

Finally, as I suspect John knows, if each of the dice is coloured differently, then there are 651*5! distinct ways in which dice arrangements can add up to 20.

Comment: I don't think the counting at the end is quite right.  The only combination that would have $120$ permutations is the yahtzee.  The rest will have more than that.  The colors alone can be ordered in $120$ ways on the line.  But attach numbers to the colors, and the permutations for that combination go up, right?

Comment: I believe you are correct.  So I edited my answer, and I believe that what remains answers the question.

Comment: You did bring up something I was wondering about, though: If order matters, how does it matter?  I think the answer that the OP was looking for (whether s/he specified it or not) was that the dice were lined up, but not colored.  If the dice were colored, but not lined up, or colored *and* lined up, the answer would be different.

Comment: The question posed was, "How many ways can 5 dice produce a total of 20?"  I took the question that way.  If you want to know the answer to another question in which order is an important consideration, then why don't you ask that question yourself?

Comment: Did you notice that I offered an answer to this question, too?  What I meant was: "This was something I was wondering about *when answering this question*..."  My apologies for assuming you saw that.

Comment: That, and the answer you have now is in essence the one I provided (which says that order is not important).  The OP commented, "Wouldn't this mean that the order of the dice doesn't matter?"  So, well ... yes, apparently order *is* important.  I then edited my answer to take ordering into account.  But, as your answer showed, there can be more than one type of ordering, which is why I commented.  I may figure out the answer at some point myself, but it's not really a question I need the answer to.  I commented in the context of this question being vague to begin with.